# How to stop Notifications from the app

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uilocalnotification

Inside a switch I have a trigger for a notification with the ability to repeat itself. How can I make it stop when the switch is off?

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute
notification.alertBody = "Please Look at me"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() else { return }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel all local notifications using

```
cancelAllLocalNotifications
```

or go thru the list of scheduled notifications with

```
scheduledLocalNotifications
```

and cancel that specific one (marked by specifying the 'userInfo' field of the notification).